# The project was not built since its path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.sun.jersey.api.view.viewable.

Tags: java, jersey

So, I updated `jersey` version to the latest and while deploying the app I started getting this error. This class doesn't even exist in the latest version of `jersey` so I cannot add (missing jar file) in the classpath but somehow classloader is still referencing it. How can I fix this issue.

Steps done already:

- clean and build
- update project via maven
- restart ide

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be an ideal solution but the only way to get rid of this issue for me was to add the lower version of the jersey jars. As I said, this is not the right approach because now I got two version of Jersey jars in my classpath.

We have to carefully build the project and test all the services just to make sure they are working as expected because jersey get confuse what to pick up if there are two version of jars.

In these kind of cases, usually the third party api breaks because of the fact that you don't provide the implementation of certain interfaces or abstract classes which are not in the latest version but the compiler refers to the lower version and look for an implementation. Therefore I don't like this approach at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command to update in IDE.

Just like for eclipse:

Run **mvn eclipse:eclipse** to update ur Eclipse. It refreshes the project after completion of the command run.

Comment: I did that it looked like it brought in bunch of jars but still having the same issue.

Comment: You can right-click on your project then Maven > Update Snapshots. If you cannot find this option, you can select the checkbox "Update Snapshots" in the maven build configuration in eclipse to have the dependencies updated.